# Finding an endomorphism with given characteristics.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have been trying the following, but can't get my head around how to go on. I need to find an endomorphism $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in the canonical basis) such that:

1. Its rank is 2.
2. Its trace is 4.
3. $(2,1,1)$ is one of its eigenvectors.
4. $U = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x+y-z = 0\}$ is an eigenspace.

I can derive some information from this facts, but I can't come close to actually defining an endomorphism. So far I know:

1. If the rank of $f$ is 2, then $\dim(f(\mathbb{R}^3))=2$ and by the rank-nullity theorem, the nullity of $f$ must be 1.
2. If its trace is four, the sum of its eigenvalues is also four: $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 4$

I don't know how to use the rest of the information provided. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you mean that $(2,1,1)$ is an eigenvector, yes?

Comment: Definitely! Sorry, lack of sleep and a long day aren't precisely making me quick. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the vectors $v_1=(2,1,1)$, $v_2=(1,0,1)$, and $v_3=(0,1,1)$. Clearly, $\bigl\langle\{v_2,v_3\}\bigr\rangle=U$. So, take $f$ such that:

- $f(v_1)=0$;
- $f(v_2)=2v_2$;
- $f(v_3)=2v_3$

and you're done. Note that if $f$ is constructed this way, then$$f(x,y,z)=(-2y+2z,-x+y+z,-x-y+3z).$$

Comment: I don't understand. Why does that approach work? Why $f(v_1)=0$? Sorry if I am slow, it's been a long day. Is it because of the rank must be 2?

Comment: The matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix},$$and therefore the trace of $f$ is $4$. Since $f(v_1)=0$, $v_1$ is an eigenvalue of $f$. And the range of $f$ is $U$, which is $2$-dimensional. Therefore, $\operatorname{rank}f=2$.

Comment: Jesus Christ. I've been thinking about this problem for hours because I thought it involved way more calculations. Thank you very much. As a last question, could've be decided any combination of eigenvalues such that their sum is 4 instead of 2 and 2?

Comment: No. This is the only choice. Don't forget that $0$ must be an eigenvalue and that all vectors of $U$ must be eigenvectors of $f$ with the same eigenvalue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why zero must be a eigenvalue :( I just understood that 2 should be a repeated eigenvalue, though, so thanks for that!

Comment: Since $\operatorname{rank}f=2$, it follows from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim\ker f=1$. But $\ker f\neq\{0\}\iff 0$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!